# OpenCover XUnit 2.0

Tags: sonarqube, xunit, opencover, xunit2

I am trying to configure XUnit 2.0 with OpenCover to be ultimately fed into SonarQube. However, I cannot figure out how to get the .xml results file out of the process. There doesn't seem to be an argument for this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I can't work out what you problem is - are you having trouble getting opencover to run or having trouble getting the produced results out of sonarqube?

Comment: Hi Shaun, sorry I should have been clearer. I can get opencover to run with xunit, however I can't get the test results into sonarqube. I get the coverage results but not the test results. So I get no test metrics in sonarqube. Thanks for your help